# Is it possible to use if tag in <on-entry> state in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow-2

I have written the flow as below in spring web-flow 2. But I get error as **invalid content**.

```
<on-entry>
<decision-state="check">
<if test="some condition" then="x state" else="y state"/>
</decision-state>
</on-entry>

<view-state id="x state">
<evaluate expression="...."/>
</view-state>
```

Is there any alternative to use if tag in on-entry state?
Can we use decision-state in on-entry?

If the condition is true, I have to evaluate the method in `<on-entry>` state. Otherwise, it shouldn't evaluate in `<on-entry>` state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first, `<on-entry>` only makes sense inside a state.
second, you cannot define a state inside an `<on-entry>`

what you should do is just define your `decision-state` and webflow will automatically use it as the entry point.

```
<decision-state id="check">
    <if test="some condition" then="xState" else="yState"/>
</decision-state>

<view-state id="xState">
    <evaluate expression="...."/>
</view-state>

<view-state id="yState">
    <evaluate expression="...."/>
</view-state>
```

let's look at this flow, the entry point is obviously `check`, which is your decision-state because both `x state` and `y state` are called by it.

so you flow chart is
             x state

          /
check

          \
             y state
because there is no other way. and I guess this is the behaviour you want

[EDIT]
here is an example with 2 action-states:

```
<decision-state id="check">
    <if test="some condition" then="xState" else="yState"/>
</decision-state>

<action-state id="xState">
    <evaluate expression="expr1"/>
    <transition on="success" to="zState"/>
</action-state>

<action-state id="ySate">
    <evaluate expression="expr2"/>
    <transition on="success" to="zState"/>
</action-state>

<view-state id="zState">
</view-state>
```

x action-state

          / (evaluate expr1) \
check                           view-state

          \                           /
              y action-state
            (evaluate expr2)

Comment: You removed the on-entry in the flow but I need it because there is already evaluate expression exists in on-entry state.This on-entry state is enclosed in a view-state.Here the evaluate expression should be executed based on a **if condition**.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say. maybe you should use decision-state then 2 action-states to evaluate your expressions then redirect both action-states to your view state

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.I resolved this in other way.

Answer (score 2):

yes use lambda if condition
 x = y ? "true result" : "false result"

```
    <view-state id="viewId">
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.varx == x ? Bean.dosomethingX() : Bean.somethingY()" result="flowScope.varResult" />
        </on-entry>
    </view-state>
```

or on start

```
        <on-start>
            <evaluate expression="flowScope.varx == x ? Bean.somethingX(): Bean.somethingY() " result="flowScope.varResult" />
        </on-start>
```